# Calling a LinearLayout from a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-framelayout

I load a Fragment in my FrameLayout and I have a button in the fragment. When the button is clicked, I want to start a new Activity. But when I start the activity, the button is still there in the new Activity. How do I prevent this?

**MainActivity.Java**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/main">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame"/>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity2**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Test"/>
```

**Fragment onCreate**

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

**Fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.anonymous.kalanjali2015.HomeFragment">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="next"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

Comment: You should add your code...

Comment: Please add your code or provide some link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your `MainActivity2` layout is transparent and in stack below your `MainActivity`, your fragment lies so buttons of that fragment is visible in your `MainActivity2`.

Do one thing: put some dark background color it will not be visible `android:background="#ff0000"` in the `LinearLayout` of `MainActivity2.xml`